# Schema design in MongoDB — to replicate data or not

Tags: mongodb, schema

I have a `Share` collection which stores a document for every time a user has shared a `Link` in my application. The schema looks like this:

```
{
  "userId": String
  "linkId": String,
  "dateCreated": Date
}
```

In my application I am making requests for these documents, but my application requires that the information referenced by the `userId` and `linkId` properties is fully resolved/populated/joined (not sure on the terminology) in order to display the information as needed. Thus, every request for a `Share` document results in a lookup for the subsequent `User` and `Link` documents. Furthermore, each `Link` has a parent `Feed` document which must also be looked up. This means I have some spagehetti-like code to perform each find operation in a series (3 in total). Yet, the application only needs some of the data found in these calls (one or two properties). That said, the application does need the entire `Link` document.

This is very slow, and I am wondering whether I should just be replicating the data in the `Share` document itself. In my head, this is fine because most of the data will not change, but some of it might (i.e. a `User`'s username). This is suggesting of a `Share` schema design like so:

```
{
  "userId": String,
  "user": {
    "username": String,
    "name": String,
  },
  "linkId": String,
  "link": {}, // all of the `Link` data
  "feed": {
    "title": String
  }
  "dateCreated": Date
}
```

What is the consensus on optimising data for the application with regards to this? Do you recommend that I replicate the data and write some glue code to ensure the replicated username gets updated if it changes (for example), or can you recommend a better solution (with details on why)? My other worry about replicating data in this manner is, what if I needed more data in the `Share` document further down the line?

Comment: The typical answer with nosql will be to denormalize.  Denormalized fields are then updated as they're changed (perhaps asynchronously).  I suppose later on if the schema changes for `Share`, you'd deal with that then via a manual update, etc.  Personally I like to keep the id and data in the same field, e.g. `{user: { _id: ObjectId, ... }}`

Comment: By "denormalize" do you mean to replicate the data?

Comment: Yes, "denormalize" means "copy and replicate". That will lead to a different type of pasta, perhaps "linguini code" instead of "spaghetti code".

Comment: If it still goes just as well with my bolognese then I think we have a solution.